# Custom keyboard shortcut for workspace switcher

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, workspace-switcher

I would like to change the keyboard shortcut for the workspace switcher in Unitity. How can I do that? Currently it is set to <kbd>Supre</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. I would like to set it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. Strangely enough I can find this option neither under the System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts nor in ccsm..

Comment: You should be able to switch between workspaces using Ctrl+Alt+Arrow keys.

Comment: @radu-rdeanu: Well, I would like to get to windows switcher by pressing Ctrl+` and not super+s. Going from one workspace to another I already configured..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**CompizConfig Settings Manager** [image: Install CompizConfig Settings Manager]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/). Go to **Desktop** > **Expo**, select **Bindings** tab and change the value of **Expo key** as you wish:

[image: CompizConfig Settings Manager]

Generally, if you want to find quickly a keyboard shortcut which is set in CompizConfig Settings Manager, you can use **Advanced Search** option (**Settings value** must to be selected):

[image: Search in Compiz]

Comment: holly cow. This is extremely useful

Comment: Do you happen to also know how to change the supre+w behaviour ? I could, of course, start a new ticket for that :)

Comment: @arthur I don't find now... You can [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) if you wish.

Comment: Found it: it is under scale plugin (initiate window picker for all Windows) :-) Thanks mate!

Comment: @arthur Yep, you're right; check the new method that I added at my answer.

Comment: @radu-rdeanu: this is awesome!

Comment: What tool did you use to make this pretty graphic? Amazing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unity Tweak Tool.

### installation

UTT is in the Raring repos, so if you're running 13.04 you can just use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Or through the software center:

[image: Install unity-tweak-tool]

If you are running Precise or Quantal you will need to use the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

### the workspace switcher

Open UTT; under the "Window Manager" section open "Workspace Settings".

[image]

Now under "Workspace Shortcuts" will be the "Start workspace switcher entry", opposite of which will be the key currently assigned to the workspace switcher. Click on that key name and press the new key you want to activate the workspace switcher.

[image]
[image]

Log out and log back in and you're done!

I personally prefer using UTT over CCSM because it only modifies dconf values and hence is a safer tool to use.

Comment: This approach using `unity-tweak-tool` does not work in 16.04 for binding keys such as Alt or Windows.